# What is the jQuery selector for same class names but one is hidden?

Tags: jquery

I'm targeting this div to add HTML after (using jQuery after) this:

```
<div class="wpv-setting-container wpv-setting-container-horizontal wpv-settings-layout-markup js-wpv-settings-layout-extra">
```

For some reason due to technical requirements of the application, I'm forced to use the class `wpv-settings-layout-markup`. However, there is also another div that contains this class but its hidden:

```
<div style="display:none;" class="wpv-settings-templates wpv-setting-container wpv-setting-container-horizontal wpv-settings-layout-markup" id="attached-content-templates">
```

Now when I use the class name in my jQuery after method, it is added to BOTH the visible and invisible div.

```
$(".wpv-settings-layout-markup").after('data here');
```

How can I revise this selector:

```
$(".wpv-settings-layout-markup")
```

To target only the visible div? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `:visible` selector

```
$(".wpv-settings-layout-markup:visible")
```

More information can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
$(".wpv-settings-layout-markup:visible")
```